# Regular expression for unicode and english characters with max text length

Tags: regex, unicode

I'm looking for the way to match native language characters with english letters of 15 to 40 characters max. I need a regular expression for the below sample text.

text: දුරකථන for sale

I found this `\p{Sinhala}` for unicode characters which I can use with the regular expression.

The text I want to match is : දුරකථන for sale

I tried this regular expression to match the above text but didn't work.

```
/^[\p{Sinhala}\p{Zs}]{15,40}$/
```

I'm using Reactjs for this work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
/^[\p{Sinhala}\p{Latin}\p{Zs}]{15,40}$/
```

1. ^: Anchors the match at the beginning of the string.
2. [\p{Sinhala}\p{Latin}\p{Zs}]: Matches any character that is either a
   Sinhala character (\p{Sinhala}), a Latin character (\p{Latin}), or a
   space character (\p{Zs}).
3. {15,40}: Specifies that the matched sequence should be between 15
   and 40 characters in length.
4. $: Anchors the match at the end of the string.

Comment: your solution isn't validating the example text and even english letters are not identified. ex: phone for sale in sri lanka , දුරකථන for sale in sri lanka either of these text are not validating.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the regex issue by using this code `/[\s^\u0000-\u007F]{15,20}/`